# With $F$ adjoint to $G$ show that exists a functorial morphism $FG\rightarrow 1_D$

Tags: abstract-algebra, adjoint-functors, functors

Let $C,D$ be categories, $F:C\rightarrow D$ a functor that is adjoint at the left to a functor $G:D\rightarrow C$. Show that exists a functorial morphism $FG\rightarrow 1_D$ and $1_C\rightarrow GF$ (that is not necessarily a isomorphism).

I started doing this:

I wanna show that exists functorial morphisms like
\begin{align*}
    \alpha: FG&\rightarrow 1_D \\
    \beta: 1_C&\rightarrow GF
\end{align*}

So, for each $X\in C$ I need to identifie some $\beta_X:X\rightarrow GFX$.

I know that $F$ is a functor that is adjoint at the left to a functor $G$, this means that for each $X\in C$ and $Y\in D$ exists a bijection
$$\Phi_{X,Y}: Hom_C(X,GY)\rightarrow Hom_D(FX,Y).$$

As $F:C\rightarrow D$ then for $X\in C$ we have $FX\in D$ then exists a bijection
$$\Phi_{X,FX}:Hom_C(X,GFX)\rightarrow Hom_D(FX,FX)$$
as $1_{FX}\in Hom_D(FX,FX)$ we have that exists $f_X \in Hom_C(X,GFX)$ such that $\Phi_{X,FX}(f_X)=1_{FX}$, so define for each $X\in C$
$$\beta_X=f_X$$

Now to show that this wil make a functorial morphism I need to show that the square is commutative with $u:X\rightarrow Y$
[image]

That's what I can't do.

Comment: Hint : use the fact that $\Phi_{X,Y}$ is natural in both variables

Comment: I imagine that's what I have to use, I just don't see how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\Phi$ is a natural isomorphism, for any $f:X\to Y$, the following diagram commutes :
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,GFX) @>\Phi_{X,FX}>>\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal D}(FX,FX) \\
@V GFu \circ - VV @V Fu\circ - VV\\
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,GFY)  @> \Phi_{X,FY} >> \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal D}(FX,FY) \\
@A -\circ u AA  @A - \circ Fu AA\\
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(Y,GFY) @>\Phi_{Y,FY}>> \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal D}(FY,FY)  
\end{CD}$$

Now, if we follow the elements $\beta_X \in\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,GFX) $ and $\beta_Y \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(Y,GFY)$, we see they both arrive at $Fu \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal D}(FX,FY)$. Since $\Phi_{X,FY}$ is an isomorphism, we must have :
$$GF u \circ \beta_X = \beta_Y \circ u$$

which is what we wanted.

Comment: On my definition of $F$ is a functor that is adjoint at the left to a functor $G$ the square below should be $Hom_D(FX,FY)\rightarrow Hom_D(FY,FY)$ and $Hom_C(X,GFY)\rightarrow Hom_C(Y,GFY)$

Comment: The $\operatorname{Hom}$ functor is contravariant in its first variable, so the morphism $u: X\to Y$ gives a map $\operatorname{Hom}(FY,FY) \to \operatorname{Hom}(FX,FY)$

Comment: Got it, thanks.